# LocationManager not working / display location

Tags: android, geolocation, android-gps

I'm working to get my geolocation using `LocationManager` and `LocationListener` im getting a result when I use this in my android emulator it loggings the location but it is not the accurate location. but when i try to my phone it is not logging already the location, I dont know where i went wrong here. i already declare all the requirements in `Manifest` and set my phone to `High accuary` on the gps and connect them into a wifi.

here is my code:

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.cmsapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashscreenActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".TokenActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is the file where i try to log the gelocation:

```
package com.example.cmsapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.Browser;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.cmsapp.Http.Url;
import com.example.cmsapp.Service.AsyncResponse;
import com.example.cmsapp.Service.Internet;
import com.example.cmsapp.Service.Session;

import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Session session = new Session(MainActivity.this);

    Button btnCall, btnSms;
    Intent intent;
    WebView wvMap;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnCall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCall);
        btnSms = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSms);
        wvMap = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvMap);

        wvMap.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        WebSettings wSettings = wvMap.getSettings();

        wSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        wSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        wSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);

        wvMap.loadUrl(Url.map);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Log.i("", "Location: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, locationListener);

        btnCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+639959870688"));

                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btnSms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Thread threadStart = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                final Session session = new Session(MainActivity.this);
                                Internet internet = new Internet(new AsyncResponse() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void processFinish(String result) {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }, MainActivity.this);
                                String url_query = "?token=" + session.get_session("token") + "&fullname=" + session.get_session("fullname")
                                        + "&area=" + session.get_session("area");
                                url_query = url_query.replace("-", "_");
                                url_query = url_query.replace(" ", "%20");
                                internet.execute("get", Url.requestSms + url_query);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };

                threadStart.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: "but when i try to my phone it is not logging already the location" - what do you mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you allow actual your app permissions?
How about the below setup?

Settings > Apps & notifications > App info > com.example.cmsapp(your app name) > Permissions > Location

And what about the result of the following code?

```
final boolean isGpsProviderEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

In the case of me, the emulator could not get the location, but in my phone it could get the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Location location;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    boolean isGPSEnabled =false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;        


myLocationDataSource = new MyLocationDataSource(this);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (location == null) {
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    }
                }
            }

            if(location != null){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
            }
        }
```

you forgot to Request for a location.